# JavaFx build problem "Main class not found"

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I need to create an executable file for my program (.exe). However when running the executable I get the message com / abstudio / printersreports / Launcher not found -Failed to launch JVM. Program works in IDE

My gradle file

```
    plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'idea'
}
sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Main-Class': 'com.abstudio.printersreports.Launcher'
        )
    }
}

sourceSets.main {
    java {
        srcDir 'src/main/java' //assume that your source codes are inside this path
    }
    resources {
        srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/main/resources']
        exclude "**/*.java"
    }
}
compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jfoenix/jfoenix
    implementation group: 'com.jfoenix', name: 'jfoenix', version: '8.0.10'
    compile 'com.jfoenix:jfoenix:8.0.10'

    compile group: 'de.jensd', name: 'fontawesomefx', version: '8.1'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.22'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itextpdf
    compile group: 'com.itextpdf', name: 'itextpdf', version: '5.5.13.2'

    compile group: 'org.apache.derby', name: 'derby', version: '10.14.1.0'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.controlsfx/controlsfx
    compile group: 'org.controlsfx', name: 'controlsfx', version: '8.40.18'

    compile "com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0"
    compile 'com.google.zxing:javase:3.3.0'

}
mainClassName = 'com.abstudio.printersreports.Launcher'
```

Artifacts looks like this
[image: Artifacts 1]
[image: Artifacts 2]

Comment: Don't know if this is the Problem, but why do you have two classes with a main method? `Main` and `Launcher`

Comment: The first was Main in which the function is main and start. So I read on stackOverflow to create a class only with the main function (in my case the Launcher class). It is the same problem with her and without her

Comment: I am not a Gradle expert but I think it should be  'Main-Class': 'main.java.com.abstudio.printersreports.Launcher'

Comment: Same problem :/